# how to remove table row after delete it from the database using ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i was trying to add `$tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000, function () {
                            $tr.remove();`

to delete the row once i clicked the delete button but it's not working ..

```
function Delete(ID) {
        var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");

        if (ans) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ ID: ID }),
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000, function () {
                        $tr.remove();

                    });
                    //alert(result);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {

                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

the ajax function is working well and the row is deleted form the database..

Comment: How are you calling `Delete` ?

Comment: Where do you ever define `$tr`?

Comment: i'm calling the delete on click ..
@Shyju

Comment: i don't know i thought i defined when i used it like this  , am i ?@Shyju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will fail because you are using `$tr` which is not defined inside the method. (If you have defined it outside, that is even bad).

You have to get access to the `tr` where the delete button/link was present. If you are using the `onclick` event handler to call the Delete method, you can pass `this` to your Delete method along with the id you are passing and get access to the tr from that.

jQuery `closest` method will be handy here

```
 <a href="#" onclick="Delete(someId,this)">Delete</a>
```

And in the js

```
function Delete(id,t) {

    $tr= $(t).closest("tr");

    // make the ajax  call
    // Use $tr now in your ajax call's success event

    $tr.find('td').fadeOut(700, function () {
        $tr.remove();    
    });
}
```

If you are using unobutrusive javascript to bind the `click` event of the delete button / link, you can use `$(this)` to get a reference to the item which was clicked. In this case, you can actually build the url to delete action method with the id in it and set as the href value of the link

```
<td>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Delete",new { id=1234})" class="delete-item">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Replace `1234` with actual id value you have in your code
and in the js file, you can read the url of the clicked link using the `attr` method.

```
$(function () {

    $("a.delete-item").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

        $.post(url).done(function() {
            $tr.find('td').fadeOut(700,function() {
                    $tr.remove();
            });
        });

    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/nucasaxeju/edit?html,js,output) is a working jsfiddle for both solutions for your reference (*excluded the ajax call*).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
success: function (result) {
                    var selector = "#"+ID;
                    $(selector ).fadeOut(1000);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                            $(selector ).remove()
                        }, 1000);
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use id for

```
<td id="td...">
```

**Replace**

```
$tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $tr.remove();
});
```

**By**

```
$('#td...').fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $('#td...').remove();
});
```